# I want to know something about this mutate list function

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

The original question is to create a mutate_list function which take list as parameter. The function will modify the list in following ways:
-Any element that is an integer is multipled by 2
-Any element that is a boolean is inverted (True becomes False, False becomes True)
-Any element that is a string has its first and last letters removed
-The 0th element is set to the string Hello, regardless of its original type

The code I wrote was:

```
def mutate_list (L):
 L[0]="Hello"
  for i in range (1,len(L)):
   if isinstance(L[i], int):
    L[i]=L[i]*2
   if isinstance(L[i], string):
    L(i).replace(L(i)[1:-1])
   if isinstance(L[i], bool):
    L[i]=not L[i]
```

This code just wont run, could any one give me some hint what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There were a few issues:

1. The indentation needed to be fixed.
2. `L(i).replace(L(i)[1:-1])` was incorrect.
3. `string` is undefined.  You mean `str`.
4. `elif` is needed since booleans test True as both integers and booleans.

Thus:

```
def mutate_list (L):
  L[0]="Hello"
  for i in range (1,len(L)):
   if isinstance(L[i], bool):
    L[i]=not L[i]
   elif isinstance(L[i], int):
    L[i]=L[i]*2
   elif isinstance(L[i], str):
    L[i] = L[i][1:-1]
```

This mutates `L` in place.  For example:

```
>>> L = [True, True, 'abc', 3]
>>> mutate_list(L)
>>> L
['Hello', False, 'b', 6]
```

#### Alternative

Another approach is list comprehension.  This returns a new list according the the rules you specify:

```
['Hello'] + [not a if isinstance(a, bool) else a[1:-1] if isinstance(a, str) else 2*a if isinstance(a, int) else a for a in L[1:]]
```

For example:

```
>>> L = [True, True, 'abc', 3]
>>> ['Hello'] + [not a if isinstance(a, bool) else a[1:-1] if isinstance(a, str) else 2*a if isinstance(a, int) else a for a in L[1:]]
['Hello', False, 'b', 6]
```

Comment: something that you fixed but didn't point out: `isinstance(L[i], string)` is a `NameError` unless you've named something `string`, and isn't what you want regardless (I suppose...unless you've done `string = str` for some reason.

Comment: Although you don't need to return `L`. This is a list mutation. No reason to return a result (much like `list.sort`)

Comment: I actually tried to use str instead of string and it actually works. However, when I run it, it gives me an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.TypeError: mutate_list() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given @John1024

Comment: Ok I just figure out where went wrong, thanks for the answer @John1024